# Why are all prime numbers are congruent to 1 or 5 (mod6)?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I understand that any natural number congruent to 2 or 4 (mod6) is even and that 3 is the only prime congruent to 3(mod6). Thus, any prime, p > 3, must be congruent to either 1 or 5 (mod 6).

I just don't understand the reasoning behind why any natural number congruent to 2 or 4 (mod6) is even and that any natural number congruent to 3(mod6) is a multiple of 3.

Could someone explain why this is true?

Comment: If, say, $n=2+6m=2\times (1+3m)$ then $2\,|\,n$.  The other cases are parallel.

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of sense. Thank you @lulu!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is eliminate the other cases, and use the definitions of modular congruence, divisibility, and primality. Recall:

$$x \equiv y \pmod z \iff z \mid x-y \iff \exists k \in \Bbb Z^+ \text{ such that } x-y = kz$$

(Or at least, we use the positive integers in this context usually.)

So, if $p \equiv 0 \pmod 6$, then $p = 6k$ for an integer $k$. That means $p$ isn't prime.

If $p \equiv 3 \pmod 6$, then $p = 6k+3$ for an integer $k$. But then $p=3(k+1)$, and thus is not prime (assuming $p > 3$).

If $p\equiv 2,4 \pmod 6$ then you have that $p=6k+2 = 2(3k+1)$ or $p = 6k+4 = 2(3k+2)$, respectively, for integers $k$, and thus no primality (assuming $p > 3$).

Thus, the only remaining cases are $1$ and $5$.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense @Eeevee Trainer, thank you!

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs